# ZFS pool size discrepancy after rsync-ing

Tags: rsync, zfs, truenas

I am trying to `rsync` data one of the volumes in a ZFS pool to an exfat formatted drive. The volume is only 1.3 TB but the `rsync` got up to syncing 3+ TB worth of data. I killed the `rsync` so I could figure out what is wrong.

The ZFS pool:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ zpool list
NAME     SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP  HEALTH  ALTROOT
backup  7.25T  3.59T  3.66T         -     0%    49%  1.00x  ONLINE  -
```

The volumes and their mountpoints:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ zfs list
NAME                                                      USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
backup                                                   2.61T  2.49T  35.4M  /backup
backup/.system                                           1.97M  2.49T   140K  legacy
backup/.system/configs-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx   593K  2.49T   593K  legacy
backup/.system/cores                                      692K  2.49T   692K  legacy
backup/.system/rrd-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx       128K  2.49T   128K  legacy
backup/.system/samba4                                     337K  2.49T   337K  legacy
backup/.system/syslog-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx    128K  2.49T   128K  legacy
backup/vol1                                              1.26T  2.49T  1.26T  /backup/vol1
backup/vol2                                               128K  2.49T   128K  /backup/vol2
backup/vol3                                              1.78G  2.49T  1.78G  /backup/vol3
backup/vol4                                              1.34T  2.49T  1.34T  /backup/vol4
backup/vol5                                              4.51G  2.49T  4.51G  /backup/vol5
```

The size on disk of `/backup/vol1`:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ du -sh /backup/vol1
1.3T    /backup/vol1
```

How much data was copied after doing an `rsync` for a couple days:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ rsync -avzh --progress --no-o --no-g /backup/vol1 /media/ubuntu/external_drive/freenas/
...
...
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ du -sh /media/ubuntu/external_drive/freenas/vol1
3.2T    /media/ubuntu/external_drive/freenas/vol1
```

I killed it after seeing how much was transferred.

Comment: Do you have compression enabled on ZFS? That could explain the discrepancy. To query the uncompressed size, use “zfs list -o logicalused”. I’m not sure how rsync treats empty (zeroed) blocks, so it could also be counting those even though ZFS isn’t.

Comment: Even `logicalused` only shows 1.4 TB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to expand on my comment above, this will happen under two circumstances that I can think of:

- The files / volumes you're sending are using block saving techniques (compression, dedup, or snapshots/clones). ZFS has saved you some space internally, so the ZFS property `used` is small, but `rsync` still has to read all the logical (uncompressed, undeduped, un-snapshot-sharing) data because it has no idea about those features. You can figure out how much logical data there is by running `zfs list -o logicalused` (or `logicalreferenced` if you have snapshots).
- The files / volumes you're trying to send are sparse. From your comment above, I believe this is the case you're in. `rsync` is sending all the unwritten blocks of your volume, even though they're all zeroed out (because they've never been written to). Try using the `--sparse` argument to `rsync`, as described in [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/66338/how-do-you-synchronise-huge-sparse-files-vm-disk-images-between-machines), to work around this behavior, and then using `--in-place` for subsequent syncs to avoid re-syncing the entire file instead of just the parts that have changed.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan How did it go? Don’t forget to accept / upvote the answer if it helped :).

Comment: I am still working on it. The computer I was copying to had issues and now I am on vacation. I will continue when I get back from vacation and report back then.